# Special Functions.

Tags: special-functions

How do I show that

$\Gamma(v,x)=(v-1)\Gamma(v-1,x) + x^{v-1} e^{-v}$.

I know I should use Integration by parts on the formula for upper incomplete gamma function. But the result is not coming out. A hint would be helpful, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the integration by parts? If $x < y$ you have
$$\int_x^y t^{v-1}e^{-t} \, dt = - y^{v-1}e^{-y} + x^{v-1} e^{-x} + (v-1) \int_x^y t^{v-2} e^{-t} \, dt.$$
Now let $y \to \infty$ to conclude (since both integrals converge) that
$$\int_x^\infty t^{v-1} e^{-t} \, dt = x^{v-1}e^{-x} + (v-1) \int_x^\infty t^{v-2} e^{-t} \, dt.$$

Comment: @Umbero P Thanks very much. My problem was the wrong choice of u and dv in the integration by parts.